# sites for Video Background Loops?

Tags: video

What some sites for Video Background Loops? I wonder if any know where I am get vj loop? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Creative Commons licenses](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/) permit liberal media distribution, redistribution, and re-mixing.  I did a very simple Google search and immediately found this [source of CC-licensed VJ loops](http://www.beeple-crap.com/vjclips.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are also many sites with Video Background Loops. 
Use any search engine to find them. A good site to Video Loops is here: [Video Loops](http://limeartgroup.com/products/video-loops/)